# How to pass value to another view-controllers?

Tags: iphone

I want to pass localstringtextnote to Uploadviewcontroller by this way ,

```
UIViewController *controllerNew = [[UploadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UploadView" bundle:nil owner:self];
        controllerNew.localStringtextnote = localStringtextnote;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controllerNew animated:YES];
        [controllerNew release];
```

but i got this error"@property localstringtextnote not fond in the object of type uiviewcontroller"
or 
i want to pass through modalTransistionstyle

```
UploadViewController *aSecondViewController = [[UploadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UploadView" bundle:nil];
        aSecondViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        [self presentModalViewController:aSecondViewController animated:YES];


        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

How to do this?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the variable

```
NSString *_localStringtextnote;
```

in `UploadViewController.h` file.

Also add a property for that variable in the same file.

```
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *localStringtextnote;
```

In .m file, synthesize that inside the implementation.

```
@synthesize localStringtextnote=_localStringtextnote;
```

Now run the app.

Comment: will it work with UIViewController *controllerNew = [[UploadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UploadView" bundle:nil owner:self];
        controllerNew.localStringtextnote = localStringtextnote;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controllerNew animated:YES];
        [controllerNew release];

Comment: UIViewController *controllerNew = [[UploadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UploadView" bundle:nil owner:self];
        controllerNew.localStringtextnote = _localStringtextnote;
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:controllerNew animated:YES];
  [controllerNew release]; again the same error message

Comment: Declare `controllerNew` as object of `UploadViewController` instead of `UIViewController`.

Comment: Any issue so that you keep it as object of `UIViewController`?

Answer (score 1):

```
        UploadViewController *controllerNew = [[UploadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UploadView" bundle:nil owner:self];
        controllerNew.localStringtextnote = localStringtextnote;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controllerNew animated:YES];
        [controllerNew release];
```

change your uiview controller to UploadViewController as uiview controller doesn't have any property localStringtextnote

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `localStringtextnote` as the property in the `UploadViewController` as `@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString * localStringtextnote;` and synthesize in `.m` file.

Answer (score -1):

create a new method in controllerNew (don't forget to declare it in *.h file):

```
-(id) setParams:(NSString*)str {
   localStringtextnote = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:str];
   return self;
}
```

Then, when you need to puth this view controller:

```
    UploadViewController *controllerNew = [[UploadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UploadView" bundle:nil owner:self];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controllerNew animated:YES];
controllerNew = [controllerNew setParams:localStringtextnote];
    [controllerNew release];
```

Comment: This makes no sense, only init methods should return self like this. The debugger will still complain that the method `setParams` is unknown because it is not declared in the `UIViewController` class.

Comment: then declare it in .h file. i did it hudrets of times.

Comment: What you edited the `UIViewController.h` you should inherit from `UIViewController` not edit it's .h file.

Comment: whats your problem? I didn't ever even think about editing SDK files. I'm talking about his UploadViewController.h

Comment: Yes you create an instance of `UploadViewController.h` but place it in a variable of type `UIViewController` this will mean that the compiler does not seen any methods of `UploadViewController` and only the methods of `UIViewController` which does not contain the `setParams` method. The example given by you will compile but give the warning that the method `setParams` is unknown.

Comment: oh... i just copied his code and didnt put that in mind. offcorse  there must be UploadViewController type. It seems you have a bad day today: pushing me for this accident so long, and downvoting... if anyone just tell me, that this isn't work, I'd just see carefuly in the code and fided out this myself.